# Building an android map application for indoor building

Tags: android, location

I have started my first android app, and managed to get the interface up.

I know how to get the user location outside of the buildings, by using GPS.

But for inside building, it is harder or it is not locking the position at all. So how do i accurately locate user location inside a building? I am thinking of using both Cell ID and Wifi/Mobile Network together. Is it efficient?

Also, after getting the location, how do i make it constantly follow the user movement like the Google navigation/GPS apps on the road(which follows the car movement)?

and final question, what method do i use to display the building's inside layout? is there any satellite kind of method that automatically locate the building's layout? or do i need to manually draw the map?

one more additional question, is it possible to actually include Google Street View inside the app for the indoor state of the building?

I am using android 4.1.1 sdk, and live outside US/UK that currently not supported by google for its navigation/street view, which is Malaysia.

THank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a tough task.

Simple answer,  depends on what precision we are talking about. But since you are talking about indoor localisation then I guess few meteres at max. This is very hard to achieve in reality using CellID/wifi/gps.

You might look for solutions more like this

http://www.sociopatterns.org/

But I am guessing that this is for smaller project.
Note that solutions like that are also tough because of the battery usage.
You really have to have a good reason for "following" people indoor precisely.

As for indoor mapping, checkout Google Indoor Mapping

http://maps.google.com/help/maps/starthere/index.html

Comment: Oh then I guess CellID/Wifi/GPS are not a choice at all. I have no idea what the website you gave me is about. Seems complicated as I only expect to use either CellID/Wifi/GPS. Well lets say only to get the user location only maybe? Lets leave the "following" part out of the picture first.

and I assume the Google Indoor Mapping, I have to draw my own maps first right? then upload it. I am looking at it and seems like it. But is it possible to call those maps/floor plans i use in my own app? i mean like, when open the app, it automatically loads the floor plan, not the whole google maps.

Comment: if you already have the app, simply go to the places where you want geo-location to work. and check the results, as they may differ depending on the place on earth and building you are in. Think how foursquare does it with checkins for instance. Its far from precise.

Comment: As for google indoor maps, as far as i can recall. you have to do exactly what u say, draw, upload, use

Comment: alright. thank you for your help. I think i got a rough idea on how to actually implement this.

Comment: no i actually change the scope of my project in the end, made it smaller and different approach. its too big of a project to do it alone. :(